# Nginx proxy directives

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use the following nginx configuration so that a cookie is shared across all subdomains. Unfortunately, it seems like the lines with X-Forwarded-For and proxy_cookie_domain are completely ignored (have no effect) by nginx. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
server {
    server_name discuss.mysite.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/discuss.log;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_cookie_domain ~^(.*)$ "$1; Domain=.discuss.mysite.com";
    }
}
```

This is the output from curl -I:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 18:14:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: destination_url=http%3A%2F%2Fdiscuss.mysite.com%2F; path=/
Set-Cookie: _forum_session=eTZVVGFzNWJDNjdnV0l0SGFlWDF2MDN2VUtQSnZ0NlN2MmVaR3NKR1A3VFB3MUZFVmRhbTlYNmwxS29TaWkvT05rQmtSaFQwbUhUVjNKeDEwV0JNRGc9PS0teXVLQU92YlRWalJ4WnhpTXNzNkxSdz09--1f472148823725a4e1ad45c0c3b48618c6560be3; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: __profilin=p%3Dt; path=/
X-Request-Id: 1cb6fc64-f7b9-45d9-9647-94fbedc44345
X-Runtime: 0.367952
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on wrong way, because directive `proxy_set_header` set additional header *from* nginx *to* backend, not *from* backend+nginx *to* your `curl` client; this is the reason why you don't see them.

There are 2 options to send additional header *to* a client

- set them on backend
- use `add_header` directive in proper location

But those header will be 'static' ones (except sent from backend, where you can construct it as you wish) - this will be incorrect while working with cookies. To serve cookies correctly you should use `ngx_http_userid_module` module and it directives.

To share a cookie across subdomains, use

```
userid_domain  .mysite.com;
# or ".discuss.mysite.com" for 4-th level of subdomains
userid_path    /;
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

```
Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response
code equals 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307.
```

Try to add the headers on the port 8080 directive

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header